# catamorphical function Either a a -> a?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a catamorphical function with this signature :

`fct :: Either a a -> a`

unlifting an either with the same types on the left and the right...

Comment: I can't find one on Hoogle either. You just mean that you want `fct (Left a) = a` and `fct (Right a) = a`? Well you can easily write that yourself (I just wrote it there, see :p )

Comment: [`Data.Morphism.Cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/catamorphism-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Morphism-Cata.html) can generate `'either`, but with the more generic form (`(a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`). In fact, it's so common, [that's in `base` as well](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either). In that case, `fct = either id id`, but I don't see the benefit over Robin's answer above.

Comment: @RobinZigmond of course Robin but the goal was to use something already and standard...

Comment: thank you @Bartek Banachewicz ! I was exactly looking for that !

Comment: @NicolasHenin K, I'll post this as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Data.Morphism.Cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/catamorphism-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Morphism-Cata.html) can generate `'either`, but with the more generic form:

```
'either :: ((a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c)
```

In fact, it's so common, [that it's in base as well](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either). In that case:

```
fct = either id id
```

Comment: same spirit with 'maybe' :-)